# Uploadify Restrict File Types

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, uploadify

I'm able to restrict files to videos on initial click.

[image]

However, when I change the dropdown I can upload anything.

[image]

Here is my code, what am I missing?

```
        'fileDesc': 'Video (*.avi, *.mov, *.mp4, *.mpeg, *.3gp, *.flv, *.f4v, *.swf, *.wmv, *.mkv )',
        'fileExt': '*.avi; *.mov; *.mp4; *.mpeg; *.3gp; *.flv; *.f4v; *.swf; *.wmv; *.mkv',
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do more validation than the "accept" attribute. One place to start would be to set up a new RegExp and check for those extensions in the uploaded file with match(). Do this when the user clicks submit. You could also capture the file path and use if(indexOf('.mov') > 0) to test for certain extensions (use a for or while loop to test an array of allowed extensions).